# Android RecyclerView GridLayout size issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout, gridlayoutmanager, recyclerview-layout

I am trying to achieve the following result.

[Expected Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3NRa.png)

And I am getting the following result.

[Actual Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yzq9.png)

can anyone guide me to achieve the expected results.

I have shared my code below,

```
 mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MyGridActivity.this,3);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
 adapter = new MyGridAdapterAdapter(MyGridActivity.this,arrayList);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Sharing my item_layout xml file for grid list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cardView">

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/health_2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Health" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Try `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content` on your root layout.

Comment: nope. results are the same..

Comment: try `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `match_parent` in root layout, cardview and linear layout

Answer (score 1):

Your `TextView` length is disturbing GridItems

Either give your parent layout a fixed height or give your `TextView` a fixed height

try this ...

update your `TextView` from

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Health" />
```

to

```
    <TextView
        android:lines="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Health" />
```

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: hi thanks for the code. it fixed my vertical size but not fixing my horizontal size.

Comment: that worked for me as showed on the screen try giving "match_parent" width to your ImageView as well

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this code just copy and paste in your Activity while initializing

```
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MyGridActivity.this,3);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);//This line

adapter = new MyGridAdapterAdapter(MyGridActivity.this,arrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thanks for the contribution. 
i have updated the code.